# Does Cesiumjs support blender and OBJ model?

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to render many buildings on the map with Cesiumjs, and Does cesiumjs support blender and OBJ model?

Answer (score 3):

Cesium supports [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF), which is an open standard from Khronos designed for 3D assets on the web.  The Cesium website has a drag-and-drop converter to convert COLLADA files to glTF:

http://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html

You can export COLLADA files from Blender.

Patrick

Comment: very old answer here but can Obj models be loaded in Cesium in latest 1.52 version? Any update on this please.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two way visualize your 3d model

1. Using Cesium Ion (Ion can convert to 3Dtiles or GLTF)
2. Convert to GLTF

You have to convert 3D OBJ file to GLTF
Blender can export 3D model as GLTF or GLB

After Conversion, for load GLTF model at CesiumJS sandcastle sample
(https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Models.html)